# How to optimize lambda at runtime?

Tags: c#, lambda

I've got a test job to optimize lambda-expression at runtime. Assuming the lambda contains some "heavy" function calls, what I need is to change the lambda so that all that function calls were cached into temporary variables, which then can substitute the actual function calls in the lambda body.

It must be a function that gets a lambda as a parameter, and returns optimized lambda which you can call then.

I wonder what section of C# is this at all? I mean, like, "learn about reflections" or "learn about generics". What do I need to learn in this case?

Comment: Expression Trees is a specific chapter of C# books. It is semi-connected to reflection (that you need to know at least a little). It is only tangentially connected to generics (just because you could need to do reflection on generic methods :-) and the `Expression.Lambda<>` uses generics... so it is more connected to strings or to arrays than to generics)

Comment: You can look up [Memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), that seems to be the issue here.

Comment: aren't lamdba expressions all compiled up by runtime?

Comment: @Ewan Lambda Expression are two things: `Func<int, int> f = x => x + 1` that is compiled by the compiler, and `Expression<Func<int, int>> f = x => x + 1` that isn't. This second one is an "expression tree" and can be parsed/analyzed/modified at runtime (and then compiled) (if we want to be precise, it can't be modified... But it is nearly easy to create a copy with some changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [Memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) is the technique you are looking for.

Here is an article that explains how you can achieve [memoization in c# using generics and lambda expression](http://iserialized.com/memoization-using-generics-and-lambda-expressions/).

Finally, you can find an actual implementation of the technique in [ReactiveUI](http://reactiveui.net/) [MemoizingMRUCache](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/rxui4/ReactiveUI/MemoizingMRUCache.cs).

Comment: Between knowing the name of a pattern and writing an expression tree rewriter for it, the distance is quite big.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your heavy function calls are [deterministic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_algorithm), and you can prove that they are always called with the same parameters, you can't do it.

For example, in C#

```
var lst = new List<string> { "Foo", "Bar" };

bool r1 = lst.Remove("Foo"); // true, and has modified lst
bool r2 = lst.Remove("Foo"); // false, and hasn't modified lst

bool r3 = lst.Remove("Bar"); // true, and has modified lst, note different parameter
bool r4 = lst.Remove("Baz"); // false, and hasn't modified lst, note different parameter
```

How can you detect if `Remove` is deterministic or not? You can't (technically you could disassemble it and check it, but it is very difficult)... And then how could you detect if it is being called with the same parameters? This is doable, but quite difficult.

Now... as a test job... I see three possibilities:

- it is a false test, where you must comprehend this and report it
- you didn't comprehend the test job
- you didn't give us some important informations (for example that you have to replace some specific method calls that don't have parameters and are static or something similar, and that are guaranteed to be deterministic)

Comment: @yaapelsinko And how can you check that x an y are constant and don't change in the middle?

Comment: @xanatos - when the assumption is that F is deterministic, all you need is the _starting_ values of x and y.

Comment: @HenkHolterman What? No, a function is deterministic based on the parameters.. If you change parameters, the result changes. *a deterministic algorithm is an algorithm which, given a particular input, will always produce the same output* (from the wiki)... Example... Add(1, 2) == 3, Add(1, 3) == 5, Add(1, 2) == 3, Add(1, 2) == 3, Add(1, 2) == 3... Add is deterministic, but if it changes the parameters the result changes

Comment: It becomes even more complex with reference types... `int c1 = Enumerable.Count(myList); myList.Add(1); int c2 = Enumerable.Count(myList); `. Now... `Enumerable.Count` is deterministic, `myList` is the same (as in the same reference)... But `myList` has changed between the lines.

Comment: Yes.  "...you need the [starting] values of x and y". What's unclear about that?

Comment: @HenkHolterman If there are two calls to F(x, y); F(x, y), for starting values I mean the values passed the first time. But English isn't my first language.